# MQL4 Name an Array with Chart Symbol & Period

Tags: arrays

I have an EA with a Static array HighLevel[2000];

I want to save the array when I exit the chart so it can be loaded again.

The EA can run on multiple charts and timeframes so rather than having an EA for each Chart and time period so that when they save they don't over write eachother, I need to declare the array name as:-

double Symbol()+Period()+"HighLevel"[2000];

this does not work and I can't see how to do it, any help very much appreciated,

Thank you.

I have an EA with a Static array HighLevel[2000];

I want to save the array when I exit the chart so it can be loaded again. I need it to have the name of chart

Comment: Please add more code, are the result you have on console and that isn't the one you're expecting. Can you also add the proper tag of the language you're using?